# Is there an analytic $f(x)$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \neq \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\int_a^b{T_k(x)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, taylor-expansion, power-series

I've found some examples when $\sum\int \neq \int\sum$ but I'm interested in how 'likely' I am to get the wrong answer if I do this manipulation when solving integrals, which often have you integrating the Taylor series of a function termwise.

Is there a real analytic function $f(x)$ with its Taylor expansion $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty{T_k(x)}$ such that $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \neq \sum_{k=0}^\infty{\int_a^b{T_k(x)}}$ for some $a$ and $b$

Comment: The Taylor expansion of an analytic function converges uniformly and absolutely in compact subsets of the disk of convergence. If $[a,b]$ is contained within the disk of convergence, then you can exchange the order of summation and integration.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function has Taylor series that converge to that function at every point, as Mittens pointed out (and as a consequence of Abel's theorem), we have that the series of functions, which Taylor seires is, **converges uniformly** to that function at every point. Then, by Integrable Limit theorem and Integral of sum theorem:

$$\int_a^b \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n = 1}^N f_n = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\int_a^b \sum_{n = 1}^N f_n = \lim\limits_{N \to \infty} \sum_{n = 1}^N \int_a^b f_n$$